# Is it possible to disable retry mechanism for uWSGI after harakiri?

Tags: uwsgi, web.py

I am running a webpy web server with uWSGI and there are some requests that take too long. After setting up harakiri mode I noticed that after a request is killed it is retried one more time.

Is it possible to disable this behavior?

The running command is:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --http-socket={socket} --chdir={dir} --master --module=start --max-requests=1500 --harakiri=20 --carbon-max-retry=0 --rawrouter-max-retries=0 --sslrouter-max-retries=0 --processes=1 --enable-threads --ignore-sigpipe --die-on-term --worker-reload-mercy=5 --pidfile=/tmp/uwsgi.pid
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

uWSGI IRC user damjan helped me debugging this. There is no problem with uWSGI, the retires are generated by the browser. If you try with curl requests are killed without problems.

If you have nginx on top of uWSGI you might also want to take a look at: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11217477